# Liferay server not redirecting to default page when session expires

Tags: liferay-7

I want that Liferay 7.0 server should redirect to default page when session expires.

Expected result when session expires - Liferay should redirect to http://localhost/web/customportal/login

Actual result when session expires - Liferay is redirecting to 
http://localhost/web/guest

I have followed this article - https://dev.liferay.com/en/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-1/general-settings

Updated "portal-ext.properties" by adding

> default.logout.page.path=/web/customportal/login 
>   auth.forward.by.last.path=true
>
> Updated in Control Panel → Configuration → Instance Settings. 
>  Default
>   Logout Page = /web/customportal/login

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my question, add below in "portal-ext.properties"

> session.timeout.redirect.on.expire=true 
>   company.default.home.url=/web/customportal/login

Please refer the following URL for the solution - https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-71039